# How to select the whole page, but not the input field inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

```
<body>
  <div>Sample div</div>
  <input type='text'/>
</body>

$(document).delegate('body *:not(input)', 'keyup', function(e){
    if((e.keyCode || e.which) == 39){ //right arrow
        $('#next_image').click();
    }
    if((e.keyCode || e.which) == 37){ //left arrow
        $('#prev_image').click();
    }
}
```

I'm using jQuery Cycle library to setup slideshow. It's more like a photo album, where you can use keyboard shortcuts to do some stuff. So, the slideshow is the whole page, which also contains input fields. Hence, when you are writing a text inside of input field and try to move cursor with keyboard (left and right arrow buttons), it would fire the event and scroll to the next/prev image.

Any ideas on how to enable keyup events on everything BUT the input field? Obviously, current selector doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with `.delegate()` instead of the currently-favored [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$(document).delegate(':not(input)', 'keyup', function (e)
{
    if (e.which === 39) $('#next_image').click();
    else if (e.which === 37) $('#prev_image').click();
});
```

- jQuery normalizes key code information, so you only need to check [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)
- If you did have to check `keyCode` and `which`,  `(e.keyCode || e.which) == 39` would not work properly, since `||` will evaluate to the first truthy operand, or the second operand if both are falsy. To put it differently: you'd have to check each one separately, like this:

  ```
  if (e.which === 39 || e.keyCode === 39)
  ```
- It's generally better to use `===` instead of `==`. See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

---

> doesn't work... it's still firing the keyup event inside of `<input>`

Ah yes. I'm thinking it's because of event bubbling.

I've seen it solved using an extra event handler (imgur caption boxes in the [gallery](https://imgur.com/gallery)):

```
$('input').live('keyup', function (e) {
    if(!e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey) {
        if(e.keyCode==37 || e.keyCode==39 || e.keyCode==13) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/DQusL/

Comment: doesn't work... it's still firing the keyup event inside of <input>

Comment: Hm. This is probably due to event bubbling.